# In application loading and running programs

Tags: c, assembly, execution, stm32, program-counter

I want to write two main programs P1 and P2. P1 will be loaded into STM32 board with JTAG, and the binary file generated after P2 compilation will be written in STM32 board external flash memory.
In P1, after doing somethings, I want to load P2 into RAM and run it. So, the program counter will jump to P2.

**P1:**

```
#include ......

void main(void)
{
    printf("Hello, I am program 1 !\n");

    //TO DO: load and run P2
}
```

**P2:**

```
#include ......

void main(void)
{
    printf("Hello, I am program 2 !\n");
}
```

So, is there any way to do so if it is possible.

Comment: Have you tried using [`system`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/)?

Comment: There is no portable way of loading another program's code *into your own process* via C. But you can start another process, as Drew pointed out, and wait for that to return before continuing. Anything else would be very much OS-dependent.

Comment: Well, I dont want to have 2 executing process. Only one program is executed at a time. The idea of using system is usefull and may solve the problem incase of using Linux OS. But I am using STM32 discovery board, there is no OS to be loaded. the binary file is loaded into flash memory. Wahen powering on the board, the bootloader will load the binary program from flash into RAM and run it. I want to do something like this: The bootloader load P1 and run it, P1 load P2 and run it

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in comments, portable options are limited.  However, given that you are working with embedded STM32, we'll assume some degree of non-portability is acceptable.

GCC and friends allow a function to be defined with the *noreturn* attribute, so something like this will accomplish an unconditonal jump to P2.

```
    #define EXT_FLASH_ADDRESS  (0x60000000)
    void __attribute__((noreturn)) (*p2_entry)(void) = EXT_FLASH_ADDRESS;
    void main(void)
    {
        printf("Hello, I am program 1 !\n");

        p2_entry();
    }
```

Some points to note:

- The declaration of `p2_entry()` may vary with your toolchain.  The illustrated version simply informs GCC that it does not have to maintain the call stack in the usual manner. Many other toolchains provide a similar mechanism.
- You'll need to modify the `EXT_FLASH_ADDRESS` appropriately.  The illustrated value is representative, so you'll need to update it with the proper value. (Consult your eval board's documentation.)

Comment: You could use _Noreturn, which is standard C11 and portable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is no problem with doing this, this is exactly what bootloaders do and have been doing since the dark ages.